# MySQL RegExp: A Digit who is not followed by a Digit

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a query like this:

`SELECT * FROM`mes`WHERE text REGEXP '#11'`

and i whant to get all meanings of #11 eg:

```
<b>#11</b>

#11a
```

but not that case with a digit after the number:

*#112*

so i tired to build a reg exp "not" als {0}

```
SELECT * FROM `mes` WHERE text REGEXP '#11[[:digit:]]{0}'
```

but this just gave me something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `mes` WHERE text REGEXP '#11^[:digit:]'
```

Comment: For what case do you mean? "#11#" should be found by the regexp.

Answer (score 2):

^ means not in a regex

```
SELECT * FROM `mes` WHERE text REGEXP '#11[^0-9]*'
```